# php preg_replace working only if there's ending space in string

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I have this pattern:

```
preg_replace_callback('#@abc\((.*?)\)(.*?)@end.#is', ..
```

My template string:

```
$test = "@abc('test')<h1>test</h1>@end"; // not working
$test2 = "@abc('test')<h1>test</h1>@end "; // working
```

Why it doesn't work if there's no space after @end?

Comment: See that dot at the end of your regex ...?

Comment: Yeah :-) Thanks. If you want credit feel free to post an answer. If not I'm gonna delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Rizier123 pointed out, this is the correct regex:

```
preg_replace_callback('#@abc\((.*?)\)(.*?)@end#is', ..
```